# Server Side Includes for certain files

Tags: apache-2.2, ssis

at the moment, all of my .shtml files are being parsed by SSI. Some of these pages do not have SSI and it would be more efficient if they did not have to go through SSI. Is there anyway to specify a certain files or a group of files to be parsed and have the rest of it parsed instead of having ALL .shtml files parsed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the [**Apache Doc**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/security_tips.html):

> All SSI-enabled files have to be
>   parsed by Apache, whether or not there
>   are any SSI directives included within
>   the files.

Can't you just rename them to .html?

Comment: I could.. but that would mean diving into all the files that we have to change the appropriate links to reflect that change. So I was hoping for something less drastic.